# Insert circular text into sections in SVG using Javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

It's me again with my "Wheel of life" thing. But since last time i've got many steps further.
I actually arrived at the final step, adding text in sections.

Here is the code I have so far (open in full screen):

```js
d3.select('#step').on('click',function(){
    sections = document.getElementById("sections").value;
    deuxiemeEtape(sections);
});



function deuxiemeEtape(sections){
    
    var form=d3.select("#form2")
    form.append('hr');
    form.append('p')
        .html('Titres des petites sections')
        .style('text-decoration','underline')

       
    for (i=1;i<parseInt(sections)+1;i++){
        form.append('label')
            .html("Nom de la petite section "+i);
        form.append('input')
            .attr('type','text')
            .attr('id','ps'+i);
    }
    form.append('hr');
    form.append('p')
        .html('Titres des sections')
        .style('text-decoration','underline');
    
    
    for (i=1;i<(parseInt(sections)+2)/2;i++){
        form.append('label')
            .html("Nom de la section "+i);
        form.append('input')
            .attr('type','text')
            .attr('id','gs'+i);
    }
    d3.select("#circles").attr('disabled','');
    d3.select("#sections").attr('disabled','');
    d3.select("#step").attr('disabled','');
    form.append('button')
        .attr("id","create")
        .html("Créer")
        .on('click', onClickButton);
    form.append('button')
        .attr("id","reset")
        .html("Reset")
        .on('click',reloadPage);
    
}

function reloadPage(){
    window.location.reload();
}




const createSvg = (circles, sections) => {
    const svg = d3.select('#canvas');
    const width = parseInt(svg.attr('width'));
    const height = parseInt(svg.attr('height'));
    svg.selectAll('g').remove();
    const g = svg.append('g')
        .attr('transform', `translate(${width / 2},${height / 2})`);
    let i;
    for (i = parseInt(circles)+1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (i==circles){
            g.append('circle')
            .attr('r', 40 + i * 30)
            .style('fill', 'blue')
            .style('stroke', 'black');
        }else if (i==parseInt(circles)+1){
            g.append('circle')
            .attr('r', 40 + i * 30)
            .style('fill', 'red')
            .style('stroke', 'black');
        
        } else {
            g.append('circle')
            .attr('r', 40 + i * 30)
            .style('fill', 'white')
            .style('stroke', 'black');
        }
        
    }
    
   
    const angle = Math.PI * 2 / sections;
    let points = "";
    for (i = 0; i <= sections; i++) {
        if(i%2==0){
          //Regular sections
             radius = (circles) * 30 + 70;
        } else {
          //Small sections
             radius = (circles-1) * 30 + 70;
        }
        
        const x = radius * Math.sin(angle * i);
        const y = radius * -Math.cos(angle * i);
        g.append('line')
            .attr('x1', 0)
            .attr('y1', 0)
            .attr('x2', x)
            .attr('y2', y)
            .style('stroke', 'black');
        points += ` ${x},${y}`;
    }

     // Don't mind this, it's WIP
    function onPolygonClick () {
        const x = d3.event.layerX - width / 2;
        const y = d3.event.layerY - height / 2;
        const radius = Math.hypot(x, y);
        let clickAngle = Math.atan2(x, -y);
        if (clickAngle < 0){
            clickAngle = Math.PI * 2 + clickAngle;
        }
            

        const circle = Math.abs(Math.ceil((radius - 40) / 30));    
        const sector = Math.floor(clickAngle / angle)
        alert("Cliqué sur cercle "+circle+" / secteur "+sector+"");
    }

    // Don't mind this, it's WIP
    g.append('polygon')
        .attr('points', points)
        .style('fill', 'white')
        .style('stroke', 'black')
        .style('fill-opacity', 0.01)
        .style('cursor', 'pointer')
        .style('display','none') 
        .on('click', onPolygonClick);
}



function onClickButton () {
    const circles = d3.select('#circles').node().value;
    const sections = d3.select('#sections').node().value;
    createSvg(circles, sections);
}
```

```css
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-color: rgb(78, 98, 112);
}

#formulaire,#form2{
    width:9.3%
}

input{
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin:1em 0;
}

svg{
    border:3px black solid
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>SVG</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <div id="contenu">
            <div id="formulaire">
                <label>Number of circles</label>
                <input type="number" min="1" id="circles" />
                <br />
                <label>Number of sections</label>
                <input type="number" min="1" id="sections" />
                <button id="step">Suivant</button>
            </div>
            <div id="form2">
                <!-- Insert inputs here -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <svg id="canvas" height="750" width="1700">
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

So as you can see, the inputs to get the text are added below the previous one. I need to add the text of the small sections in the blue circle, and the regular sections in the red circles ! I can't figure how to do this.

Here is an exemple of how it should look with the text :
[image]

Thank you for reading this ! And thank you for answering if you do !

Comment: how do you define small sections? after adding how it should look like in circles?

Comment: @Ravikuma As I said, small sections are delimited by lines, and the text of small sections must be in the blue circle, the regular section in red circles. I'm adding an exemple of how it should looks when I add text ! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could achieve it to append text but not making text center aligned exactly.

[image]

```js
d3.select('#step').on('click', function() {
  sections = document.getElementById("sections").value;
  deuxiemeEtape(sections);
});



function deuxiemeEtape(sections) {

  var form = d3.select("#form2")
  form.append('hr');
  form.append('p')
    .html('Titres des petites sections')
    .style('text-decoration', 'underline')


  for (i = 1; i < parseInt(sections) + 1; i++) {
    form.append('label')
      .html("Nom de la petite section " + i);
    form.append('input')
      .attr('class', 'sub-sections')
      .attr('type', 'text')
      .attr('id', 'ps' + i);
  }
  form.append('hr');
  form.append('p')
    .html('Titres des sections')
    .style('text-decoration', 'underline');


  for (i = 1; i < (parseInt(sections) + 2) / 2; i++) {
    form.append('label')
      .html("Nom de la section " + i);
    form.append('input')
      .attr('class', 'sections')
      .attr('type', 'text')
      .attr('id', 'gs' + i);
  }
  d3.select("#circles").attr('disabled', '');
  d3.select("#sections").attr('disabled', '');
  d3.select("#step").attr('disabled', '');
  form.append('button')
    .attr("id", "create")
    .html("Créer")
    .on('click', onClickButton);
  form.append('button')
    .attr("id", "reset")
    .html("Reset")
    .on('click', reloadPage);

}

function reloadPage() {
  window.location.reload();
}


const createSvg = (circles, sections) => {
  const svg = d3.select('#canvas');
  const width = parseInt(svg.attr('width'));
  const height = parseInt(svg.attr('height'));
  svg.selectAll('g').remove();
  const g = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${width / 2},${height / 2})`);

  const archThickness = 30;
  const fullCircle = 2 * 3.14;

  //adding inner sections
  const arcSizeSmallSections = fullCircle / sections;
  const subSectionInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.sub-sections');
  for (let i = 0; i < circles; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < sections; j++) {
      if (i + 1 === circles) {
        appendArcs(g, i, j, archThickness, arcSizeSmallSections, 'blue', subSectionInputs[j].value);
      } else {
        appendArcs(g, i, j, archThickness, arcSizeSmallSections, 'white', i + 1);
      }

    }
  }

  // adding outer sections
  const mergeSplits = Math.ceil(sections / 2);
  const arcSizeSections = fullCircle / sections;
  const sectionInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.sections');
  const endAngle = 2 * arcSizeSections;
  for (let j = 0; j < mergeSplits; j++) {
    g.append("path")
      .attr("d", d3.arc()
        .innerRadius(circles * archThickness)
        .outerRadius((circles + 1) * archThickness)
        .startAngle(j * endAngle)
        .endAngle(((j + 1) * endAngle) > fullCircle ? fullCircle : (j + 1) * endAngle)
      )
      .attr("id", () => 'section' + circles + j)
      .attr('stroke', 'black')
      .attr('fill', 'red');
    g.append("text")
      .attr("class", "monthText")
      .attr("dy", 22)
      .append("textPath")
      .attr("startOffset", "22%")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("xlink:href", () => "#section" + circles + j)
      .text(() => sectionInputs[j].value);
  }
}


function appendArcs(parent, i, j, archThickness, arcSize, color, text) {

  parent
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", d3.arc()
      .innerRadius(i * archThickness)
      .outerRadius((i + 1) * archThickness)
      .startAngle(j * arcSize)
      .endAngle((j + 1) * arcSize)
    )
    .attr("id", () => 'section' + i + j)
    .attr('stroke', 'black')
    .attr('fill', color);
  if (text) {
    parent.append("text")
      .attr("class", "monthText")
      .attr("dy", 22)
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .append("textPath")
      .attr("startOffset", "22%")
      .attr("xlink:href", () => "#section" + i + j)
      .text(() => text);
  }

}



function onClickButton() {
  const circles = d3.select('#circles').node().value;
  const sections = d3.select('#sections').node().value;
  createSvg(parseInt(circles), parseInt(sections));
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgb(78, 98, 112);
}

#formulaire,
#form2 {
  width: 9.3%
}

input {
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 1em 0;
}

svg {
  border: 3px black solid
}

.monthText {
  fill: #161414;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="contenu">
    <div id="formulaire">
      <label>Number of circles</label>
      <input type="number" min="1" id="circles" />
      <br />
      <label>Number of sections</label>
      <input type="number" min="1" id="sections" />
      <button id="step">Suivant</button>
    </div>
    <div id="form2">
      <!-- Insert inputs here -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <svg id="canvas" height="750" width="1700">
            </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Added support for dynamic sub sections.**

```js
d3.select('#step').on('click', function() {
  sections = document.getElementById("sections").value;
  deuxiemeEtape(sections);
});



function deuxiemeEtape(sections) {

  var form = d3.select("#form2")
  form.append('hr');
  form.append('p').html('Titres des sections').style('text-decoration', 'underline');
  for (i = 1; i <= parseInt(sections); i++) {
    let ind = 0,
      row = i;

    const secGroup = form.append('div').attr('class', 'section');
    const sec = secGroup.append('div').attr('class', 'section-info');
    sec.append('label').html("Nom de la section " + i);
    sec.append('input').attr('type', 'text');
    sec.append('button').attr('type', 'button').attr('class', 'ms-2').text('Add Sub section')
      .on('click', () => {
        const subSecGroup = subSections.append('div').attr('class', 'sub-section');
        subSecGroup.append('label').html("Nom de la petite section " + row + ++ind);
        subSecGroup.append('input').attr('type', 'text');
        subSecGroup.append('button').attr('type', 'button').attr('class', 'ms-2')
          .text('Remove').on('click', () => {
            subSecGroup.remove();
          })
      });

    const subSections = secGroup.append('div').attr('class', 'ms-5 my-3 sub-sections');
    const subSecGroup = subSections.append('div').attr('class', 'sub-section');

    subSecGroup.append('label').html("Nom de la petite section " + i + 0);
    subSecGroup.append('input').attr('type', 'text');
  }


  d3.select("#circles").attr('disabled', '');
  d3.select("#sections").attr('disabled', '');
  d3.select("#step").attr('disabled', '');
  form.append('button')
    .attr("id", "create")
    .html("Créer")
    .on('click', onClickButton);
  form.append('button')
    .attr("id", "reset")
    .html("Reset")
    .on('click', reloadPage);

}

function reloadPage() {
  window.location.reload();
}


const createSvg = (circles) => {
  const svg = d3.select('#canvas');
  const width = parseInt(svg.attr('width'));
  const height = parseInt(svg.attr('height'));
  svg.selectAll('g').remove();
  const g = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${width / 2},${height / 2})`);

  const archThickness = 30;
  const fullCircle = 2 * 3.14;

  //adding inner sections
  const subSectionInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.sub-section input');
  const arcSizeSmallSections = fullCircle / subSectionInputs.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < circles; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < subSectionInputs.length; j++) {
      if (i + 1 === circles) {
        appendArcs(g, i, j, archThickness, arcSizeSmallSections, 'blue', subSectionInputs[j].value);
      } else {
        appendArcs(g, i, j, archThickness, arcSizeSmallSections, 'white', i + 1);
      }

    }
  }

  // adding outer sections
  const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.section');
  let prevAngle = 0;
  for (let j = 0; j < sections.length; j++) {
    const subSections = sections[j].querySelectorAll('.sub-section input');
    const endAngle = prevAngle + (subSections.length * arcSizeSmallSections);
    const text = sections[j].querySelector('.section-info input').value;
    g.append("path")
      .attr("d", d3.arc()
        .innerRadius(circles * archThickness)
        .outerRadius((circles + 1) * archThickness)
        .startAngle(prevAngle)
        .endAngle(endAngle)
      )
      .attr("id", () => 'section' + circles + j)
      .attr('stroke', 'black')
      .attr('fill', 'red');
    g.append("text")
      .attr("class", "monthText")
      .attr("dy", 22)
      .append("textPath")
      .attr("startOffset", "22%")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("xlink:href", () => "#section" + circles + j)
      .text(() => text);

    prevAngle = endAngle;
  }
}


function appendArcs(parent, i, j, archThickness, arcSize, color, text) {

  parent
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", d3.arc()
      .innerRadius(i * archThickness)
      .outerRadius((i + 1) * archThickness)
      .startAngle(j * arcSize)
      .endAngle((j + 1) * arcSize)
    )
    .attr("id", () => 'section' + i + j)
    .attr('stroke', 'black')
    .attr('fill', color);
  if (text) {
    parent.append("text")
      .attr("class", "monthText")
      .attr("dy", 22)
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .append("textPath")
      .attr("startOffset", "22%")
      .attr("xlink:href", () => "#section" + i + j)
      .text(() => text);
  }

}



function onClickButton() {
  const circles = d3.select('#circles').node().value;
  const sections = d3.select('#sections').node().value;
  createSvg(parseInt(circles), parseInt(sections));
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgb(78, 98, 112);
}

input {
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 1em 0;
}

svg {
  border: 3px black solid
}

.monthText {
  fill: #161414;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="contenu" class="row">
    <div id="formulaire" class="col-6">
      <label>Number of circles</label>
      <input type="number" min="1" id="circles" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <label>Number of sections</label>
      <input type="number" min="1" id="sections" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row my-2"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-2 m-auto" id="step">Suivant</button> </div>
  <div id="form2">
    <!-- Insert inputs here -->
  </div>
  <div>
    <svg id="canvas" height="750" width="1700"></svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Working perfectly ! My superior asked me now to be able to choose how many "small sections" there is in the bigger one ! Thank you so much tho, helped me a lot !

Comment: I don't think I understood it clearly, you mean user will choose first no of sections then under each section we've ask for number of sub-sections in it, right? If not, Can you elaborate it bit more. Possibly with some examples.

Comment: I'll add a new input called "Number of small section in a big one" or something like that. For example, if I enter the value 5 in this input, there must be 5 sections in a big one. 

Because if you look at the current result, it's always two sections in a bigger one. And I should be able to choose how many in a big one. Thank you again, you are saving me

Comment: @MaximeCgn, updated answer with snippet 2, I believe that's what your expectation was.

Comment: You are the best human ever ! You saved me a lot of time I was stuck in this for so long ! Thank's a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple routine to compute an arc path and draw a text along:

```js
const svg = d3.select('svg');

const arcPath = (centerX, centerY, radius, angle, length) => {
  const sector = length / radius;
  const start = angle - sector / 2;
  const end = angle + sector / 2;
  const startX = centerX + radius * Math.sin(start);
  const startY = centerY - radius * Math.cos(start);
  const endX = centerX + radius * Math.sin(end);
  const endY = centerY - radius * Math.cos(end);
  return `M ${startX},${startY} 
    A ${radius},${radius} 1 0 1 ${endX},${endY}`;
}

const angleRad = 45 * Math.PI / 180;
const path = arcPath(100,100,50,angleRad,70);
svg.select('path').attr('d', path);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg width="200" height="200">
  <path fill="none" stroke="none" id="my-path"/>
  <text>
    <textPath href="#my-path" textLength="70" >
      BLABLA
    </textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```